# PDcurses release compile on VC++ fail

Tags: pdcurses

I have an application using PDCurses. It compiles fine under debug, but when I try to compile in release mode, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'curses.h': No such file or directory
```

I don't know if I havn't set up the linker properly or what the cause may be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This message is looking for the header file: curses.h.  This specific message is not related to the linker.  There is probably an #ifdef which includes this only when doing a release build, but does not include it when doing a debug build (which may or may not be an error).  Most likely the path for the header file is not specified to your compiler.  I am not sure which compiler/version you are using, but you can add additional paths to search for header files.  This will be in the compiler options.

EDIT: Look in the file main.cpp and you should see a line which #includes the file 'curses.h'.   However, it could also be one of the header files you include there which in turn includes this file.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out that although i set up Visual C++'s search directories, it had somehow forgotten them. I created a new project and imported my source files and it is happy now